# Which impacts has openssl's end of life [2019-12-31 (LTS)]

Tags: bitcoin-core, openssl

What will happen after openssl 1.0.2 reaches end of life - 2019-12-31 (LTS) (Source: https://www.openssl.org/policies/releasestrat.html)

I remember discussion about it. Openssl does not need to be updated to 1.1.0 and it is not a security threat as not all openssl features are used and there is no security threat by using pre 1.1.0 versions.

Is it now decided that bitcoin will keep using unsupported openssl version after 1.0.2 reaches its end of-life, did something change regarding this question?

If it will be updated, is there arleady a milestone set or anything else where I could look up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not consensus critical, because BIP 66 was accepted. It might matter for SSL encryption of an RPC connection. Ideally, your RPC calls aren't crossing the network anyway, though.

Comment: I would assume, there must be also some change in build process, especially if all systems will have openssl v1.1.x or higher.